# Laravel 5.8 Adding Multiple Middleware Directly To Route

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I have a route like this:

```
Route::get("certs","CertController@index")->name('certificate.front')->middleware('auth');
```

Now I wanted to add another middleware to this route, so I tried this:

```
Route::get("certs", "CertController@index")->name('certificate.front')->middleware('prevent-back-history','auth');
```

Now I don't get any error and it works But I wonder is this way better or not:

```
Route::get("certs", "CertController@index")->name('certificate.front')->middleware(['prevent-back-history','auth']);
```

So which is better and correct in this case?

Note that I don't want to use Route groups and needed to specify the middleware name directly to the route.

Answer (score 0):

The last code is the correct way, because if you can see in your code

```
Route::get("certs", "CertController@index")->name('certificate.front')->middleware(['prevent-back-history','auth']);
```

If you wanted to have more than specific 1 middleware, you should use an array to define the middleware, so using [''] is the correct way, in case you wanted to add more middleware into the route.

Answer (score 0):

@apose7523
Both the approaches are correct and are working, so it does not matter what approach you choose

```
Route::get('example',controller)->middleware('first', 'second');
Route::get('example',controller)->middleware(['first', 'second']);
```